# Visual Studio 2012 Fakes not generating a stub for an interface that has a method with Stream return type

Tags: visual-studio-2012, moles, stub, stubbing, microsoft-fakes

Using Visual Studio 2012 to generate stubs with "Add Fakes Assembly", everything works as expected, except it is failing to generate a stub for this interface:

```
public interface IFileWrapper
{
    IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(string path);
    bool Exists(string path);
    Stream OpenReadStream(string path);
}
```

When I change the Stream to a FileStream (as Stream is an abstract class and I wanted to check if this is only happening with abstract classes), I am still not able to generate.
When I remove the method signature completely (that is deleting `Stream OpenReadStream(string path);`), I am able to generate the stub.

This is my .fake file content:

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/" Diagnostic="true" Verbosity="Noisy">
  <Assembly Name="System.IO.Abstractions"/>
  <StubGeneration>
    <Clear />
    <Add AbstractClasses="true"/>
    <Add Interfaces="true"/>
  </StubGeneration>
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Clear />
  </ShimGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

1. Any idea why is this happening and how can I avoid it?
2. There is supposed to be a Visual Studio output panel where the Fake generation results will display. I can't see any and they are not displaying in the regular build panel. Any ideas where I can find it? I searched all VS 2012 menus.

Comment: I was able to generate the stub for OpenReadStream method using VS 2012 RC version 11.0.50626.1.

Comment: For the generation results, check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051775/why-there-are-no-stubs-for-interfaces-in-microsoft-fakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a limitation in the Fakes' current implementation. You can work around this problem by switching the target framework in your unit test project from 4.0 to 4.5.

Comment: I can confirm this issue in .NET 4.5.2 and VS 2013 (2015)