# Why there are no stubs for interfaces in Microsoft.Fakes

Tags: microsoft-fakes

I'm about to use Microsoft.Fakes in my unit tests. I read a [tutorial](http://www.richonsoftware.com/post/2012/04/05/Using-Stubs-and-Shim-to-Test-with-Microsoft-Fakes-in-Visual-Studio-11.aspx) where Microsoft.Fakes creates a stub for an interface (implementred inside the solution), but in my solution stubs are available only for classes.

Can you tell me what should I do to get stubs also for all the intercaes. Both interfaces and classes are defined as public.

Answer (score 6):

Fakes generates stubs for both classes and interfaces by default. You may have bumped into one of the current limitations, which is causing Fakes to skip your interface. To troubleshoot,

- open the .Fakes file and set Verbosity attribute of the Fakes element to "Verbose"
- open TOOLS -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run and change MSBuild output verbosity to "Detailed"
- build the project that contains the .Fakes file
- open the Output window and search for the GenerateFakes task; review its output for information that explains why a particular interface was not stubbed.

In the upcoming Quarterly Update 1 of Visual Studio 2012, this information reported as warnings in the Error List window, regardless of the logging settings, which should make troubleshooting much easier.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thank you for your response.
For any reasons it didn't help. But I tested the Fakes' functionality on a new empty project at this time there were stubs for the interfaces. I made a small file compare on the both project files but I could not find any significant differences.

Answer (score 1):

You may also not have drilled down to the proper namespace.  The Fakes are generated in the same namespace as the interfaces are in in your assembly under test.  So, for example, if you're testing MyApp.Validators.IRequestValidator, in your unit test, you'll have to use `new MyApp.Validators.Fakes.StubIRequestValidator()` as opposed to `new MyApp.Fakes.StubIRequestValidator()`.